# A calculator for big numbers

Tags: c, numbers, largenumber, calc

i have to code a calculator that does adding or multiplication to numbers with maximum digits of 30 .(maximum number of operands i can enter is 20).
and this is what i came up with (it is long):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void Adding(int Result[31],int temp[30][31],int cnt)
   {
   int remainder,i,j,ResultsA[60]={0};
   for(i=0;i<30;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<30;j++)
    {
        ResultsA[j]=(ResultsA[j]+temp[i][j])%10;
        remainder=(ResultsA[j]+temp[i][j])/10;
        ResultsA[j+1] += remainder;
        if(ResultsA[30])
           {
               cnt++;
           }
    }
   }
     for(i=0;i<30;i++)
        {
            Result[i]=ResultsA[i];
        }
    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<30;j++)
      {
          temp[i][j]=0;
      }
    }

 return;
  }


 void Mul(int num,int Results[31],int Num_int[30][31],int cnt)
{
 int remainder=0,i,j,rows,x;
   for(i=0;i<1;i++)
   {
       Results[i]=1;
   }
 int temp[30][31]={0};
 for(rows=0;rows<num;rows++)
 {
     for(i=0;i<30;i++)
       {
        for(j=0;j<30;j++)
        {
            temp[i][i+j]=remainder+(Num_int[rows][j]*Results[i])%10;
            remainder=(Num_int[rows][j]*Results[i])/10;
        }
       }
       Adding(Results,temp,cnt);
 }
    return;
}



 void Plus(int num,int Nums_int[30][31],int Results[31],int cnt)
  {
      int i,j,remainder,len=0;
      for(i=0;i<num;i++)
         {
          for(j=0;j<30;j++)
             {
              Results[j]=(Results[j]+Nums_int[i][j])%10;
              remainder=(Results[j]+Nums_int[i][j])/10;
              Results[j+1]+=remainder;
              if(Results[30])
                 cnt++;
             }
         }
    return;
  }



 void str_to_int(int Nums_int[20][31],char Nums_str[20][31])
 {
  int length[20]={0},i,j;
  for(i=0;i<20;i++)
  {
    for(j=19;0<=j;j--)
    {
      while(Nums_str[i][j]<48||57<Nums_str[i][j])
             length[i]++;
    }
  }
  for(i=0;i<20;i++)
     {
       for(j=0;j<length[i];j++)
       {
         Nums_int[i][length[i]-j]=Nums_str[i][j]-'0';
       }
     }
     return;
  }


  void calcBig(char op, int operands[][31], int numOperands, int result[31],int cnt)
 {
 if (op=='+')
 {
    Plus(numOperands,operands,result,cnt);
 }
 if(op=='*')
  {
   Mul(numOperands,result,operands,cnt);
  }
  return;

 }



 int main()
 {
int i,cnt=0,y;
char x;
char Nums_str[20][31]={0};
int num, Nums_int[30][31]={0};
int Results[31]={0};
printf("select operator:\n");
scanf("%c",&x);
printf("enter number of operands:\n");
scanf("%d",&num);
printf("enter numbers <seperated by new line>:\n");
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{
 scanf("%s",Nums_str[i]);
}
 str_to_int(Nums_int,Nums_str);
  calcBig(x,Nums_int,num,Results,cnt);
 printf("result:\n");
  if(cnt)
  {
    printf("overflow!");
  }
  else{
    for(i=29;0<=i;i--)
      {
          while(Results==0)
          {
              y++;
          }
      }
      for(i=y;0<=i;i--)
        {
           printf("%d",&Results[i]);
        } 
 }
  return 0;
}
```

Num_int is the 2d array containing numbers from user , num is the number of numbers entered by user.

Mul is function for multiplying numbers in Nums_int.

str_to_int converts the number recieved from user from string to int and reverse the order.

Plus is a function to add numbers in Nums_int.

Adding is function to add numbers that are the result of multiplying a number by ever digit of the other numbers (it gives the result of multiplying two numbers).

the problem is that when i run the code i get this:

```
  select the operation:
   */+
  select number of operands:
   num
   enter numbers:
   //entering numbers
```

and after entering the numbers nothing happens and the program doesnt even end (no return 0). simply nothing happens after entering the numbers

Comment: Suggest you run your program in a debugger. And/or add more debug print statements. If you still need help after further debugging please post the *exact and complete* input and output (what you have is an incomplete approximation of the real thing - the output doesn't even match the code and the input is not given).

Comment: The cause of the problem is very likely `scanf("%c", ...)`, which is differently to the other formats in that it doesn't skip white space. Consider scanning with `" %c"` - the space character tells `scanf` to skip white space first. Alternatively, for every input, read a line with `fgets`. Then process the line with `sscanf`. (This has the benefit that prompts and inputs are always in sync.)

Comment: If you want `cnt` in `main` to be updated, you must pas its address as a pointer. As is, `cnt` will always be 0 in `main`, although it may be incremented in other functions.

Comment: Another thing about `scanf` is that if you specify a conversion, say to `int` with `%d`, the conversion may fail. That happens in your case, where you read the operator `+`. When you try to read the numbers, the input is at `/`, which isn't part of a valid number. `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions. In this case it's 0, which you don't check, and the value of `num` is indeterminate.

Comment: Where is your code that prints the values that were entered to allow you to check that the program read what you thought it read?  Where is your code that prints the values 'converted to int' format?  How do you know that code was (still) working correctly?  One of the most basic debugging techniques is to make sure that you can print the values that your program reads.  If you don't do that, you don't know whether things are working sanely.

Comment: Note: `printf("%d",&Results[i]);` should be `printf("%d",Results[i]);`  (Drop &)

Comment: `void Adding(t) {   int remainder` -->  `int remainder = 0;`  GTG

Comment: still didnt figure out how to make it work :(